# Can't share ng2-ckeditor between components. SharedModule

Tags: angular, angular2-modules

I'm trying to add [ng2-ckeditor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor) to test project. For this i added following line to systemjs.config.js

> ```
>         'ng2-ckeditor': 'npm:ng2-ckeditor/lib/CKEditor.js'
> ```

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }            from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule }        from "@angular/common";
import { FormsModule }         from "@angular/forms";
import { CKEditorModule }      from "ng2-ckeditor";

@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    CKEditorModule
],
exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    CKEditorModule
]
})
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ChangeDetectorRef }      from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AppComponent }   from "./app.component";
import { TestModule } from "./test/test.module";

@NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule, TestModule],
declarations: [AppComponent],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**test.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }            from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule }        from "@angular/common";

import { SharedModule }        from "../share/shared.module";
import { TestComponent }       from "./test.component";
import { ChildComponent } from "./child/child.component";

@NgModule({
imports: [SharedModule],
declarations: [TestComponent, ChildComponent],
exports: [TestComponent]
})
export class TestModule { }
```

But receive an error.

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: CKEDITOR is not defined

[All code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0xGPsbb9Mq2VDA3MW9xb0JtNTg?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule,SharedModule,TestModule],   //<<<<<<<-----here
declarations: [AppComponent],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**test.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
imports: [CommonModule],                        //<<<<<<<-----here
declarations: [TestComponent, ChildComponent],
exports: [TestComponent]
})
```

Comment: corrected by your advice. but get get error _Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ckeditor'_

Comment: app.component contains <test> in template. test.component contains <child>. And already child conrains <ckeditor>.